# api imagens google

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, google

Comunidade, estou tendo problemas ao usar a api de pesquisa do google (imagens), onde ela nao me retorna os resultados possiveis, por exemplo, faço uma pesquisa relacionada a carro e ela me retorna imagens que nao são de carros e nao retorna a quantidade minima que é definida como padrao que é 10.

estou usando esse exemplo da propria google:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest

onde o meu está da seguinte forma:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON Custom Search API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      function hndlr(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // in production code, item.htmlTitle should have the HTML entities escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.htmlTitle;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?searchType=image&key=MINHA_KEY&cx=MINHA_ID_MACHINE&q=carros&callback=hndlr">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Minha id machine ja está habilitada a opcao de imagens, mesmo assim nesse caso ele nao retorna nada, da o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at hndlr (testePesquisa.html:50)
    at v1?
```

Alguma luz por favor?

EDIT:

Ahhh, meio que consegui achar o problema, onde tem a opcao "sites a pesquisa" eu estava colocando: www.google.com fiz a exclusao e adicionei *.com e *.com.br e assi consegui satisfazer a minha pesquisa, mas o problema é, eu tenho mesmo que por esses termos (.com e .br....) ou tem algum termo generico? pois eu testei deixando vazio e nao retornou nada.

Comment: Coloque um `console.log(response)` no início da função e veja o que retorna. Esse erro citado é porque não existe o objeto `response.items`, logo, não tem como saber o `length` dele porque é "indefinido" (`undefined`).

Comment: nao retornou nada.